# schemaName not working for sails-postgresql

Tags: sails.js, meta, sails-postgresql

I'm using sails v1.2.2 with sails-postgresql adapter.
Looking for using Model with specific schemaName.
But relation with mapped with default schemaName (public)

```
{
   tableName : "t_role",
   meta: {
     schemaName: 'autorisation'
   }
}
```

AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: relation "public.t_role" does not exist

Comment: Did you run `sails lift --alter` or `--drop`?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i'm facing the same issue when i try to upgrade to sails v1.x.x. I Try To figure it out all day long do some debug *thx for VSCode.

ps: i dont know if this approach really solve the problem, but it works

i have to add some code in two files of waterline library here are some files

1. [forge-stage-three-query.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/utils/query/forge-stage-three-query.js)

   i dont know how exactly the waterline works but sails will add/replace(if existing) meta attributes if u want to fetch data when you query the model [add some fetch in meta properties](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/fetch)

So Ihave to add some code like this in line 82

```
s3Q.using = model.tableName;

if (typeof model.meta.schemaName !== 'undefined'){
  //meta property only set if query fetch : true
  if (typeof s3Q.meta !== 'undefined'){
    //we have to initialize propery of meta
    s3Q.meta.schemaName = model.meta.schemaName;
  }else{
    s3Q.meta = model.meta;
  }
}
```

And everythings works perfectly until i try to get some data with populate, and sails get crash the schema is set to public again, after i'm doing some debug again i found this file

2. [help-find.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js)

in this file i need to replace some code

at line 247 replace to this code

```
meta: junctionTableModel.meta,
```

at line 290 and 441 replace to this code

```
var meta = childTableModel.meta;
```

Hope this helps..